# Is there an equivalent of Subject for RxJava's Single?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

In RxJava is there anything equivalent to the `Subject` class that works for a `Single`? Presumably I'd call its `onSuccess( item )` or `onError( Throwable )` methods and the output would be forwarded to the `SingleSubscriber`.

I guess I could use an `Observable` `Subject` and transform it to a `Single` but that seems a bit clunky.

Currently using RxJava 1 but interested in the situation with RxJava 2 also.

Comment: I assume its a case of migration.  Single is still around in rxJava2, why do you want to use a Subject? https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What%27s-different-in-2.0#single

Comment: I'm mocking an Android-to-server interaction and I'd like to simulate the server's return of a JSON object.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In RxJava 2 there is [`SingleSubject`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/SingleSubject.html) that you can use as follows:

```
SingleSubject<Integer> subject1 = SingleSubject.create();

TestObserver<Integer> to1 = subject1.test();

// SingleSubjects are empty by default
to1.assertEmpty();

subject1.onSuccess(1);

// onSuccess is a terminal event with SingleSubjects
// TestObserver converts onSuccess into onNext + onComplete
to1.assertResult(1);

TestObserver<Integer> to2 = subject1.test();

// late Observers receive the terminal signal (onSuccess) too
to2.assertResult(1);
```

Unfortunately there is no equivalent available in RxJava 1. However, as you have mentioned, you can achieve the desired result by calling [`subject.toSingle()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/1.x/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#toSingle--).